# tablesorter keeps data while executing ".empty()"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, tablesorter

I have a problem with the jquery tablesorter plugin.

It doesn't clear the data after getting new data from my json source.
I tried putting the tablesorter call in different places, but it keeps adding to itself.

When I comment out the tablesorter call, it works fine.

Below is the code I use.

```
function DailyProduction() {
    $('#Container').addClass('daily');
    var firstday = Date.today().toString('MM/dd/yyyy');
    var lastday = Date.today().toString('MM/dd/yyyy');
    $("#ajaxTitle").text("DAILY PRODUCTION REPORT - (" + firstday + ")");
    $("#AjaxLoader2").show();
    $("#dynamic_rows").empty();
    $.getJSON('api/loareports.php?startdate=' + firstday + '&enddate=' + lastday,     function(json){
        $.each(json,function(i,loainf){
            var total = loainf.Avgcallsperhour;
            if (total < 15) {
                x="style=\"background-color:red; font-weight:bold; font-size:16px;\"";
            } // less then 15 is red
            else if (total >= 15 && total <= 24) {
                x="style=\"background-color:#FFDF00; color:#333; font-weight:bold; font-size:16px;\"";
            } // between 15 and 24 yellow
            else if (total > 25){
                x="style=\"background-color:green; font-weight:bold; font-size:16px;\"";
            }else {
                x="";
            } // above 25 is green
            var tblRow =
                "<tr " + x + ">"
            +"<td align='center'>"+loainf.user_name+"</td>"
            +"<td align='center'>"+loainf.last_name+"</td>"
            +"<td align='center'>"+loainf.vmin+"</td>"
            +"<td align='center'>"+loainf.vcalls+"</td>"
            +"<td align='center'>"+loainf.dialavgtime+"</td>"
            +"<td align='center'>"+loainf.xmin+"</td>"
            +"<td align='center'>"+loainf.xcalls+"</td>"
            +"<td align='center'>"+loainf.manualavgtime+"</td>"
            +"<td align='center'>"+loainf.tmin+"</td>"
            +"<td align='center'>"+loainf.tcalls+"</td>"
            +"<td align='center'>"+loainf.totalavgtime+"</td>"
            +"<td align='center'>"+loainf.leads+"</td>"
            +"<td align='center'>"+loainf.loa+"</td>"
            +"</tr>"
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#LoaReport tbody");
            $("#LoaReport").trigger("update"); 
        });
        $("#AjaxLoader2").hide();
        $("#LoaReport").tablesorter({
            sortList: [[9,1],[1,1]] 
        });
        setTimeout(DailyProduction, 10000);
    });
}
```

I am at a loss as how to make this work.
`#dynamic_rows` is this `<tbody id="dynamic_rows"></tbody>` and as said without this:

```
$("#LoaReport").tablesorter({
    sortList: [[9,1],[1,1]] 
});
```

it works fine.

Comment: Why are you calling `.tablesorter()` on every `DailyProduction` call? Put it outside of this function, and do it once. When you change the contents, use the `.trigger("update")`

Comment: I get this error. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '9' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

What about using tablesorter to do the ajax calls?